# jQuery in sharepoint returning Object Expected

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

When I add jquery to sharepoint 2007 (MOSS) and try and use it on a page no matter what I write on the client i get an "object expected" at the line/column where the "$" appears.

I have used fiddler to check that the client is downloading the query JS (which it is)

But its like its being ignore and therefor eth "$" is not understood.  Searching google everybody is saying its the selector not finding the elements but see code below I do not see how it can not find my very simple example.

In master page in header

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

version 1.4.2

On a page

```
  <a href="javascript:abc();">Testing</a>
<script>
function abc(){
        $("#simon").css("border","3px solid red");
    }
</script>
<div id="simon">
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your JS right at the bottom of your page and rewrite it as:

```
        $(function() {
        function abc() {
            $("#simon").css("border", "3px solid red");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be using jQuery in [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode, so try using:

```
jQuery("#simon").css("border","3px solid red");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd change to this overall:

```
<span id="testLink">Testing</span>
<div id="simon">Content Here</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#testLink").click(function() {
      $("#simon").css("border","3px solid red");
    });
  }
</script>
```

Best to attach your events as handlers instead of in-line, and you need to this on `document.ready`, which `$(function() { });` wrapping does.  This also lets you do all this in an included javascript file instead of including it in the page every time.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seemed to be that I was using the jquery from Googles CDN, downloaded from jquerry.com and now works.

Thanks everybody for your answers, very helpful.

Simon